# SQL query for previous year and future year data using current year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, db2

I want to get records from previous year and future year by using current year. I tried but coudnt get proper query. thanks in advance if anyone help.

I've tried this query below:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE YEAR(PRODUCTEFFECTIVEDATE) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND PRODUCTEFFECTIVEDATE> DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Give some initial sample data and desired output and your tried out code. That way we may be able to help you out.

Comment: Show your query, schema and expected output.

Comment: I tried query like below, let me correct if anything is missed
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE YEAR(PRODUCTEFFECTIVEDATE) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND PRODUCTEFFECTIVEDATE> DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE());

Answer (score 0):

In general you can query year in so many ways. This is one:

```
#for previous year
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(date_column)=YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR);

#for future year
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(date_column)=YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR);

#for previous year and future year
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(date_column)=YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
AND YEAR(date_column)=YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

You only need to subtract(-) or add(+) interval of how many years you want.

Comment: So if we need to get future 2yrs data, make it as + INTERVAL 2 YEAR?

Comment: I am trying to run above query in DB2 getting below exception:
SQL Error[42601]: An unexpected token "1" was found following "CURDATE() - INTERVAL". Expected tokens may include: "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.11.7

Comment: Your question tags TWO different RDBMS (mysql and Db2).  The answer may be relevant for mysql but is not valid for Db2.  You should not assume that the syntax is identical between different RDBMS solutions. For Db2 use `YEAR(CURRENT DATE) - 1 YEAR `   and `YEAR(CURRENT DATE) + YEAR` etc.  This syntax is valid when Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows.